# Detect if the file exists

Tags: java, file, java-io, method-call

Well the file "MyStore.obj" was attached along with the sheet I downloaded. And i'm supposed to read this file's content which is given with order of the contents.how can i make sure if it exists or not? because as you can see i tried using the method exists() but it didn't work

```
import java.io.*;

public class sheet{
public static void main(String[]args){
try{
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("MyStore.obj");

if(("MyStore.obj").exists()==false) //what can i do to fix this?

throw new FileNotFoundException("file doesn't exist");

ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);

int numOfStorageDevice=ois.readInt();
int numOfComputerGames=ois.readInt();

StorageDevice [] sd=new StorageDevice[numOfStorageDevice];

for(int n=0;n<numOfStorageDevice;n++)
 sd[n]=(StorageDevice)ois.readObject();

 ComputerGame []cg=new ComputerGame[numOfComputerGames];

 for(int m=0;m<numOfComputerGames;m++)

 cg[m]=(ComputerGame)ois.readObject();

   File file=new File("Result.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
   PrintWriter pr=new PrintWriter(fos);

 for(int i=0;i<numOfStorageDevice;i++){

 String model= sd[i].getmodel(); 
  /*and in the methodcall sd[i].getmodel() it keeps telling that
    the symbol cannot be found but i'm sure that the method exists*/

 pr.println(model);}

for(int j=0;j<numOfComputerGames;j++){

pr.println(cg[j].getname());} 
 /*i keep getting the same problem with cg[j].getname() */
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.print(e.getMessage());}
}}
```

Comment: I've removed empty lines from you wall of code, but I'd strongly advice to edit it and add proper indentation (also consider removing unrelated code like `println`).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok thanks i just did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exists()` tests if a file exists, and is thus, logically, part of the class [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html), and not of the class String. So the code should be

```
File file = new File("MyStore.obj");
if (!file.exists()) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("file doesn't exist");
}
```

Doing this check after opening a FileInputStream to the same file doesn't make much sense though, since the FileInputStream would already have thrown a FileNotFoundException if the file doesn't exist, as [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.lang.String%29) indicates.

Comment: but aren't we creating a new file with the same name? because the object file "MyStore.obj" already exists

Comment: File represents a path (existing or not) on the file system. Creating multiple instances doesn't cause any problem. And creating a File instance doesn't create any physical file on the disk. And your code doesn't create any File instance anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File data = new File("MyStore.obj");
if (!data.exists())
{
    System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
    System.exit(1);
}
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); // and so on ...
```

Comment: Why? FileInputStream will throw FileNotFoundException anyway. It's redundant.

Comment: @EJP it is redundant. And, furthermore, provides a race condition. But that was the question.

Comment: Sometimes the answer to the question is "you don't want to do that". Rather than providing a sharpened version of the original blunt knife.